# an issue with expectation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

in book's Bernt.Øks SDE i read that book and i have some serious issues :( page 21 Example 7.4.2 )

Consider n-dimensional Brownian motion $W=(W_1, \ldots ,W_n)$
starting at $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}(n ≥ 1)$ and assume $|a|>R , R\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$
Let $\tau_{k}$ be the first exit time from the annulus
$$A_{k}=\{x,R<|x|<2^{k}R\},  k=1,2,\ldots$$
and put 
$$T_{k}=\inf\{t>0,R<|x|<2^{k}R\}    $$
let $f=f_{n,k}$ be a $C^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ function with compact support such that, if $R\leq |x|\leq 2^{k}R$
$$f(x):=\begin{cases} -\log|x| & \text{when } n=2 , \\ |x|^{2-n} & \text{when } n>2. \end{cases}$$  Then,since $\Delta f=0$ in $A_{k}=\{x,R<|x|<2^{k}R\},$ we have by dynkin's formula
$$ \mathbb{E}^{x}[f(W_{\tau_k})]=f(a) \forall k $$
my question how we can find

$$\mathbb{E}^{a}[f(W_{\tau_{k}})]=f(R)P^{a}|W_{\tau_{k}}|=R]+f(2^{k}R)P^{a}|W_{\tau_{k}}|=2^{k}R]$$

indeed
we know that $f(x)=f(x)1_{R\leq |x|\leq 2^{k}R}$
then $\mathbb{E}^{a}[f(x)]=\mathbb{E}^{a}[f(x)1_{R\leq |x|\leq 2^{k}R}]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)1_{R\leq |x|\leq 2^{k}R} \, dP=\int_{{R\leq |x|\leq 2^{k}R}}f(x) \, dP= ??  $

Please respond I'll be grateful for any help offered!

Comment: @ Educ what meaning do you give to $f(R)$ ?

Comment: Hi TheBridge i mean by $f(R)$ image of $R(\in \mathbb{R}^{n})$ by function $f$

Comment: @ Educ : So what meaning do you give to $R<|x|<2^k.R$ if $R\in \mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: @Educ Note that your definition of the stopping time $T_k$ (resp. $\tau_k$, as it is denoted later on) doesn't make sense at all, since the stopping condition does not depend on $t$.

Comment: hi thanks saz but i've wrote it as it's on the book just check the  Bernt.Øks SDE

Comment: Not in my edition. (And to be honest, I really can't stand this book, but that's a totally different matter.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equality

$$\mathbb{E}^a[f(W_{\tau_k})] = f(R) \cdot \mathbb{P}^a[|W_{\tau_k}|=R] + f(2^k \cdot R) \cdot \mathbb{P}^a[|W_{\tau_k}|=2^k \cdot R]$$

follows from the fact that

$$|W_{\tau_k}| = R \cdot 1_{\{|W_{\tau_k}|=R\}} + 2^k \cdot R \cdot 1_{\{|W_{\tau_k}|=2^k \cdot R\}}$$

by the continuity of the sample paths and the definition of $\tau_k$ (in particular, $\tau_k<\infty$ a.s.). Note that this equality implies

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}^a[f(W_{\tau_k})] &= \mathbb{E}^a(f(R) \cdot 1_{\{|W_{\tau_k}|=R\}} +f(2^k \cdot R) \cdot 1_{\{|W_{\tau_k}|=2^k \cdot R\}}) \\ &= f(R) \cdot \mathbb{P}^a[|W_{\tau_k}|=R] + f(2^k \cdot R) \cdot \mathbb{P}^a[|W_{\tau_k}|=2^k \cdot R] \end{align*} $$

Comment: "by the continuity of the sample paths and the definition of τk"... And by the almost sure finiteness of $\tau_k$. +1 for the answer.

Comment: @Did Thanks, you are right; I've added the a.s. finiteness to my reasoning.

Comment: @Educ You are welcome.